# Parse smilies in Node.js and Socket.io chat app

Tags: node.js, socket.io, chat

I've created chat application based on [this project](https://github.com/tamaspiros/advanced-chat) but what I want to do now is to have parser for smilies. For example, If I write something like:

```
What's up? :)
```

That can be parsed as *"What's up? [image here]"*. Also, when someone visits room, all messages from that room needs to be parsed too. What's the easiest way to do this?

P.S. App doesn't have database.

Answer (score 2):

```
var smileyMap={
    "smile.png":[":)",":-)"],
    "sad.png":[":(",":-("]
};

var insertSmiley=function(basePath,smileys){
    var replacements=[];
    Object.keys(smileys).forEach(function(file){
        var _file="<img src=\""+basePath+file+"\"\>";
        smileys[file].forEach(function(chars){
            var reg=new RegExp(chars.replace(/([.*+?^=!:${}()|\[\]\/\\])/g, "\\$1"),"g");
            replacements.push([reg,_file]);
        });
    });
    return function(text){
        return replacements.reduce(function(line,replacement){
            return line.replace(replacement[0],replacement[1]);
        },text);
    }
}("http://example.com/images/",smileyMap);
```

"http://example.com/images/" Has to be the root Path of the smiley Images.
smileyMap has to be an Object with the filename as the key, and the smileys to be replaced as an Array.

```
insertSmiley("Hello World :-)")
```

Results in:

```
Hello World <img src="http://example.com/images/smile.png">
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use simple string interpolation based on Regex or whatever you want.

Let's imagine that we have map of smiles:

```
const SMILES_MAP = {
  ':)': 'http://link-to-smiley.png',
  ':0': 'http://link-to-another-smiley.png'
};
```

Also we have a string of our message called `message`, for instance. Let's build a function that replace all smiles with images:

```
function buildMessage(message) {
  let smiles = Object.keys(SMILES_MAP);
  smiles.forEach(smile => message = message.replace(smile, SMILES_MAP[smile]));
  return message;
}
```

Call function with message arguments and get result:

```
buildMessage("Hello there :)"); // Returns "Hello there http://link-to-smiley.png"
```